# Postgres.js, Dateranged query does not return results

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Im using Postgres.js npm module to query a postgres database

Following is the code for running the query

```js
let startDate = '2020-01-28 08:39:00';
let endDate = '2020-01-28 08:39:59';

let table = 'testtable';

console.log(
  await sql`
    select
        *
    from
        ${sql(table)}
    where created_at between ${startDate} and ${endDate}
  `
);
```

Output

```
Result(0) []
```

`created_at` is a `timestamp` column

Running the same SQL on the database yields 4 results.

Comment: 1) Are you sure you are querying the same database? 2) That there is not another table with same name but in different schema and you are having a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue? 3) You might try cranking up the Postgres logging and see what is actually hitting the database. 4) To confirm `created_at` is a `timestamp` not a `timestamptz` field? In other words confirm the timestamps are not being transformed into different values.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the db was recieving strings instead of timestamps. I've added an answer that uses `to_timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by casting the startDate and endDate to postgres timestamps inside the query.

I guess the the library does not convert strings to timestamps by default.

```
where created_at between to_timestamp(${startDate}, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH25:MI:SS') and to_timestamp(${endDate}, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH25:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Hmm, that is strange as: `select '2020-01-28 08:39:49'::timestamp between '2020-01-28 08:39:00' and '2020-01-28 08:39:59'; t` and `select '2020-01-28 08:40:00'::timestamp between '2020-01-28 08:39:00' and '2020-01-28 08:39:59'; f`. Is `created_at` a `timestamp` or a `timestamptz` field?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver its `timestamp`